# How to POST one-to-one relationship foreign key data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is the current models I'm trying to save with rest_framework.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    model_b = models.OneToOneField(ModelB, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    some_integer_field = models.IntegerField()


class ModelB(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()
```

My serializers:

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('id', 'some_integer_field', 'model_b')

class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ('id', 'data')
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that when I POST (ModelA):

```
{
    "some_integer_field": 123,
    "model_b" : "123,123,123,432,432"
}
```

I would like that when the ModelB is created in the database that the "data" field should be populated and then the ModelA would use ModelB's pk to create itself. "data" is not nullable. It has to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be done by overriding the `create()` method of serializer as,

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_b = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('id', 'some_integer_field', 'model_b')

        def create(self, validated_data):
            data_of_model_b = validated_data.pop('model_b')
            model_b_object, created = ModelB.objects.get_or_create(data=data_of_model_b)
            return ModelA.objects.create(**validated_data, model_b=model_b_object)
```

Also, add this line, **`model_b = serializers.CharField()`**, because by default **`model_b`** expect a **PK** of `ModelB`

Comment: Hmm I don't understand one thing in your answer `model_b=model_a` this part is mind-boggling.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following model

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    model_b = models.OneToOneField(ModelB, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    some_integer_field = models.IntegerField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()
```

Overwrite and implement the serializer like so

```
class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ('data')

class ModelA(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_b = ModelBSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('__all__')

   def create(self, validated_data):
       model_b_validated_data = validated_data.pop('modelB') // given you have model b key value provided in your http POST payload
       modelB = ModelB.create(**model_b_validated_data)
       modelA = ModelA.create(**validated_data)
       return modelA
```

Some parts may differ depending on what you are trying to accomplish. But essentially you want to specify the nested serializer and over write the create method for the model having the relation. This implementation django-rest calls  a writable nested serializer. See link provided http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers